Salt hydrolysis equilibrium
When we consider the hydrolysis of the anion of a weak acid (taken along with a strong base), we tend to calculate the pH, which is basically the hydrogen concentration, indirectly through the $\ce{[OH-]}$ concentration which we get from the hydrolysis of the anionic component
However, in the same system, the acid is being rejuvenated through the hydrolysis of that anion. This acid formed is yielding us $\ce{H+}$ directly
When we don't talk about salt hydrolysis and consider solely the breakdown of a weak acid into it's anionic part and H(.. we say that the pH is
$$\mathrm{pH = pKa} + \log\mathrm{\frac{[conjugate\, base]}{[acid]}}$$
In the case of salt hydrolysis.. the same reaction proceeds .. but here we tend to emphasize on the fact that we have to calculate the pH indirectly through $\ce{[OH-]}$ - which is through the ionic product of $\ce{[H+][OH-]}$ .. in the case of which comes out to be
$$\ce{[H+]} = \sqrt{\frac{Kw\cdot Ka}{c}}$$
My question is .. are these equations representing the same thing or are they different because of the two reactions occurring in the same system??

Yes. They represent the same thing. Any species in the system participates in all the reactions in which it is involved simultaneously. The concentrations of all the species remain constant when the system reaches equilibrium.
I have to point out that the equation in this part of your statement is not correct.

In the case of salt hydrolysis.. the same reaction proceeds .. but here we tend to emphasize on the fact that we have to calculate the pH indirectly through [OH−]- which is through the ionic product of [H+][OH−].. in the case of which comes out to be ...

Here is the correct approach.
Say there're two reversible reactions in the system:
$H_2O\rightleftharpoons H^+ + OH^-$
$HA\rightleftharpoons H^+ + A^-$
Let $c_0$ denote the concentration of all the $A$ species, that is $c_0=[A^-]+[HA]$. Then
$K_a=\frac{[H][A]}{[HA]}$
- Branch 1:
This is the usual approach. Assume that $K_a>>K_w$. Then we can make the approximation that $[H^+]=[A^-]$, and then $[HA]=c_0-[H^+]$. Then
$K_a=\frac{[H^+]^2}{c_0-[H^+]}$
$pH$ can be solved from this equation.
- Branch 2:
If you don't make any approximations:
$[OH^-]=K_w/[H^+]$
The $[H^+]$ comes from either the (1). hydrolysis of water, which is equal in amount with $[OH^-]$ or (2). the hydrolysis of the weak acid, which is equal in amount with $[A^-]$. Thus,
$[H^+]=[OH^-]+[A^-]=K_w/[H^+]+[A^-]$
Also, we have
$K_a=\frac{[A^-][H^+]}{c_0-[A^-]}$
$pH$ can obtained by solving the above 2 equations. There're only 2 unknowns, $[H^+]$ and $[A^-]$, and we have 2 equations, so it can be solved.
